# android file.exists does not work correctly

Tags: java, android, file, exists

In my android application I have problem with `file.exists` function. Below is my function that gets two variables. `from` is full path of file , and `to` is the path of directory in what I must copy the file. For example 
`from == "/mnt/sdcard/Media/Image/Abstact wallpapers/abstraction-360x640-0033.jpg";` and
`to == "/mnt/sdcard";`

```
public static boolean copyFile(String from, String to) {    
            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            if (sd.canWrite()) {
                int end = from.toString().lastIndexOf("/") - 1;
                String str1 = from.toString().substring(0, end);
                String str2 = from.toString().substring(end+2, from.length());
                File source = new File(str1, str2);
                File destination= new File(to, str2);
                if (source.exists()) {
                    FileChannel src = new FileInputStream(source).getChannel();
                    FileChannel dst = new FileOutputStream(destination).getChannel();
                    dst.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());
                    src.close();
                    dst.close();
                }
            }
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

When I debug it , `if (source.exists())` returns false but my file with this path exists. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: do not hardcode the path to the sdcard.Use System.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() instead.

Comment: There will be an bug in your creation of `source`. Find out the actual path you have created. source.exists will be pointing to something completely wrong. Hence does not exist.

Comment: it's pointing on the file that really exists , here is the path it shows /mnt/sdcard/Media/Image/Abstact wallpaper/abstraction-360x640-0033.jpg

Comment: Theres the problem then. That says `wallpaper`. Your origional dir says `wallpapers`. See my Edit to my answer for a better way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the way you are creating the `File` `source`.

There is a bug in it that is generating a File with the wrong directory.

So when you call `.exists` it simply doesn't, as you are referring to the wrong file path

> **public String substring (int start, int end)**
>
> Since: API Level 1
>   Returns a string containing a subsequence of characters from this string. The returned string shares this string's backing array.
>
> Parameters
>       start the offset of the first character.
>       end   the offset one past the last character.
>       Returns
>       a new string containing the characters from start to end - 1

You have misused `substring`. It get the substring from start to end -1. You have -1 yourself, so infact you have actually caused it to -2 from the folder directory.

If you remove the extra -1 and decrease start of next substring by 1, it should work.

```
int end = from.toString().lastIndexOf("/") ;
String str1 = from.toString().substring(0, end);
String str2 = from.toString().substring(end+1, from.length());
```

**EDIT:**

An improved way would be to make use of the `File` methods

```
File source = new File(from); //creates file from full path name    
String fileName = source.getName(); // get file name
File destination= new File(to, fileName ); // create destination file with name and dir.
```

Answer (score 0):

Cant see any real mistake so far, make sure your code sync on File System, fileOutputStream or FileChannel#close might not doing what you need fast enough as the File System caches some data.

Have a look at: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileDescriptor.html

I run in an issue like this when i copy smaller amounts of data mostly.